# Automatic creation/upgrade of database in devops cycle

Tags: database, microservices, application-design, continuous-delivery, devops

DevOps of our customer require that our application creates database objects and Kafka topics automatically on application start, if they are missing. Moreover, they want the application to automatically upgrade the database model, if it has changed (e.g. by using [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/)).

My response is: Do not want us to do that if you like your data. The application may contain bugs or the configuration may be wrong, and under specific circumstances something may get wrong and you may loose all your data or they may be corrupted irreparably. Moreover, automatic db model upgrade is typically the least tested part of the application. Model management should be under strict control and separated from normal application run. That's why you typically have db owner account separated from the db application account.

However, the DevOps insist on their requirement.

**Question:** Is there an approach or process that can reduce the danger of database corruption and data loss when performing automatic upgrades?

My view is: I understand the needs for DevOps cycle that needs minimal human intervention. However, here we trade DevOps comfort for data safety. Automatic Kafka topic creation may have sense when e.g. a microservice creates its local database or internal topics - when the pod with the microservice is deleted, the db and the topics are deleted as well, and this is expected and has no negative consequences. But for primary database, or for Kafka topics that contain valuable data, or for topics that serve for communication between different microservices, automatic creation or upgrades are too dangerous.

Comment: What processes would you follow to apply these changes manually and how would those manual processes prevent the problems you describe?

Comment: *"Question: Is there an approach or process that can reduce the danger of database corruption and data loss when performing automatic upgrades?"* **--** What about **backups**?

Comment: You simply need to automate the steps the admins do manually when running a separated db upgrader. This involves making a backup, switching the user account to one with more priviledges, validating the result, and preventing the application to run again when the schema isn't in the expected state. By letting a program do these steps, the process can actually become **safer** than by letting a human do this manually.

Comment: @BenCottrell The processes do not be strictly manual, but must be under control when they happen. I.e. when changes to the data model can potentially happen every time a new Pod is created, then they are not under control. When e.g. you are replacing one db column with another manually, you first create the new column, check that everything seems all right, and only then you remove the old column. How would you do this automatically? We need to change timestamp to timestamptz (in Postgre) - how would you check automatically that you changed the time-zone correctly? Human must check that, IMO.

Comment: @DocBrown I agree that the steps you describe are what needs to be done. But IMO they should be implemented in the devops scripts, not in the app. And this is the job of DevOps admins, not mine. I do not have even rights to do that. But you write that the app should implement that - can you be more specific how you imagine this is done in a safe way? E.g. you may be temporarily running the new and the old versions of the app. And while the new version tries to upgrade the db, the old version might be trying to downgrade it at the same time. With unpredictable result, of course.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Backups are necessary, but backup restore is the last mean. In a continuously running application it typically leads to data loss. (You lose the changes that occurred between the backup and the restore.)

Comment: *"And while the new version tries to upgrade the db, the old version might be trying to downgrade it at the same time"* - come on, I don't really have to tell you how to prevent this, when you are used to tools like Liquibase. Don't try to seek arguments to stick to your point - make a list of steps which have to be done, and think about how they can be implemented in a safe way. I don't see any compelling reason why putting upgrade steps into "devops" scripts (whatever that is) would be in any way safer when the upgrade is done by an upgrader program which is part of your app system.

Comment: I understand that you fear there might be done other processes by DevOps outside of the control of your application which can interfere with the upgrade. For this, I see two approaches: giving the upgrader program (which is still *your responsibility* to create) to the DevOps and let them run it at a time when it does not interfere with those "other things". Or, make your application aware of "those other processes", work together with the DevOps and develop a way of communicating it to your app system when an upgrade is currently not possible.

Comment: *"You lose the changes that occurred between the backup and the restore"* **--** Yes, but you can schedule the backup to happen right before the update and at times with low traffic.

Comment: @xarx Surely a human would need a pre-written and pre-tested query to verify the timezone change and would not be reviewing the entire dataset by-hand?    Otherwise having a human manually checking each record in the dataset sounds far more error-prone than having a well-tested verification script which can instantly compare expected results to actual results.      However, if you have a script to do this, then there's really no need for a human to be involved since an automated process can just throw up an error if it fails or the actual results don't match.

Comment: You mention DevOps, but it sounds like Dev and Ops are actually two separate teams here.

Comment: @RikD Yes, we are the Dev, and the customers' are the Ops. We provide the app images, the scripts, the sample configs etc., and they create their own configs, provide the environment dependent values, and use their Jenkins flow to deploy our application.

Comment: @BenCottrell My point is that while we test our code on ideal test data, the production data might look different. Another source of uncertainty is in that for the upgrade scripts it's hard to test anything else than a few basic scenarios, and we cannot be sure that all exceptional cases are handled properly. Moreover, I remember some command-line tools (I thing it was e.g. Oracle SqlPlus?) that didn't return error code even when there was an error.

Comment: @DocBrown If I knew what you expect me to know, I wouldn't ask here. I know what Liquibase is for, but I have no experience with it. Though I'm sure that it locks the database so that only one instance performs the db changes at a time. Try to explain to me why you "don't see any compelling reason why putting upgrade steps into 'devops' scripts (whatever that is) would be in any way safer when the upgrade is done by an upgrader program which is part of your app system".

Comment: @DocBrown We provide the upgrader program in the form of SQL scripts. Maybe Liquibase would be a better choice, but that was part of my original question. Our app uses Hibernate (which by itself can create the database automatically, but we don't use this functionality) - would it cooperate with Liquibase? What about Kafka? What's the automatic creation of Kafka topics good for if I cannot set e.g. the security (the ACLs) properly from the app? How can we support automatic deployment of our app, if we don't know its configuration values for each environment?

Comment: @xarx: concerning safety: in both cases, *you* have to write the upgrader. The chance of introducing bugs there does not get magically reduced just because you hand the upgrader over to DevOps. I cannot tell you anything about Kafka, but as I mentioned in my former comment, if your upgrader requires information from the environment, work together with the DevOps to develop a way of communicating that information.

Comment: @xarx That sounds like a testing issue - If you need the confidence against the production database then really the script should be tested against a clone/copy of that database.  On the subject of tools - if the tool doesn't work in the way you want, then find a different way of using that tool, or use a different tool, or write your own.

Comment: @BenCottrell Our customer is a bank. We have no access to the production data. We cannot change their DevOps processes. The answers and comments I've got here only confirm that such a change cannot be done without changes in the customers' Devops processes and their attitude. Their requirement to incorporate automatic upgrades into the app startup cannot be safe without satisfying many preconditions you all mention here either explicitly or implicitly. And yet, they are unable and unwilling to change anything at their side.

Comment: @BenCottrell Data anonymization should help, but it is them who would have to prepare the data and provide HW to display it.

Comment: @xarx I've worked in a bank. Regulatory requirements are painful. That being said you have a conversation here. They want automated database migrations, you need the ability to control this without seeing data. Solution 1. DevOps include QA. Get them to provide a test pipeline to test deployment of your code against a prod-copy. Provide a post migration verification program (or inline it) to test that migration looks good. Get them to verify this and communicate issue back. Solution 2. Don't downgrade. Rollback is a restore and deploy. Encourage them to use a blue-green deployment.

Answer (score 2):

***Any Change in a Database must be driven by a Program.***

> The application may contain bugs or the configuration may be wrong, and under specific circumstances something may get wrong and you may loose all your data or they may be corrupted irreparably...

This is true even of the program used to upgrade the database.

We have a solutions for this.

- Testing. Even better we can Automate Testing.
- Backups and restoration. When the program realises that the data-store is out of date, it can orchestrate a partial or full backup to a path. An older version of the program should be able to offer a restore to the backed up state.
- Immutable Store. Take a look a Fossil SCM particularly their artefact layer. Its an immutable append only store of data, every other table is derived from this data as a mere access accelerator. In this way, as long as the "artefact" format is maintained properly, you can drop every other table, index, procedure and completely rebuild the database. Even better earlier versions are usually 100% compatible.

> Moreover, automatic db model upgrade is typically the least tested part of the application

Okay, so change your culture to place emphasis on testing data-migration equally as well or even better than the rest of the application.

Spend the time to improve the quality of this.

> Model management should be under strict control and separated from normal application run.

That does depend. Is this database internal or external to your application?

If its internal then this database is under the strict control of your application. So there is no reason to separate it from your application. Of course apply good modularisation, the UI does not need to know about tables. But there is no reason why the repository module should not know how to map the data in the database to the application domain. Even if that requires migration.

If its external, then the database is its own application. So yes, your application should not have any interaction with the database which isn't the interface of the database. Probably a set of Stored Procedures, and Views. No Direct Access to the tables. But then there is no reason the database package should not know how to migrate the data, how to update the stored-procedures etc.

The short of it is that you do need this behaviour somewhere. In which application does it belong?

> That's why you typically have db owner account separated from the db application account.

Yes good point. You don't necessarily want the API itself having this sort of access in a Server model. However Batch jobs, and user programs don't have these security concerns, the user could probably already do this sort of damage directly.

But that being said, if you have an API, have an app responsible for migration.

- Run it as a loader (like many modern games have) that perform version updates and migrations.
- Run as part of the package deployment. Code is updated, then run this program to put the system state in the right way.

Alternately, have one program. It connects using the Admin connection string, and migrates the system. It then disconnects and reconnects using the everyday connection string. Promptly purging the other string from memory and then starting security compromising activities like listening on the network.

> However, here we trade DevOps comfort for data safety

Not really. You are seeing this as a trade-off because you aren't accounting for the full picture.

As I pointed out above, someone somewhere has to change the system.

- A Person is human, and humans make mistakes. Particularly in complex, or repetitive situations. Most database migrations fall right in the middle of that. This leads to expensive 4-8 eye checks, and slow processing.
- A one-off migration program. Who doesn't love blue skies, and green fields when implementing a shunting program? Chances are the program will have bugs simply by dint of being new. Let alone the actual data-migration aspects. The test infrastructure will be non-existent, or untested. Deployment practices will be a joke.
- An established program, with established design and testing architecture, that is updated with the latest transformations. Is probably much better tested, and more stable. The problem is that its a separate program, probably with separate test infrastructure. So 2x dev, and 2x testing overheads. And like you've pointed out this leads to shockingly poor testing. Although this can be countered cultural by enforcing good testing practices, and allocating the time to improve it.
- One program that is responsible for both migration, and everyday data-manipulation. All of the design and testing architecture is constantly monitored and improved. The test practices are as polished as the rest of the code. One releasable does the whole job.

Of the above options. Which one is the least risky? *Generally speaking, the last one.*

Sure there might be teams that have the culture and processes to make one of the others work, and work well. But that is relying on something that can change quickly with a new employee, or varies from team to team.

The last one works because its non-optional. The managers and the organisation must take responsibility for the code, and the data. That translates to less finger-pointing, and less finger-pointing translates to managers who must invest in the culture, and processes. Lest they sit in the comfy chair.

Admittedly if right now you are being handed this mandate from on high, then its going to hurt. The managers won't yet understand the ramifications, and you are probably right in that you aren't ready for this. The problem is if you don't improve this now, then when?

*Note: Above I say one releasable, not one package. Some releasables are comprised of many packages, and binaries (like a batch driver, a server process, and an OS client). Releasable might not be the right term for this, but none better are coming to mind right now.*

Comment: Nice answer. When I read the question first, this misconception stroke me immediately: the believe a "database upgrade" could become safer by putting in a separate program and requiring extra *manual interaction*, which is a step full of the potential of introducing even more errors.

Comment: @DocBrown Thankyou

Comment: @Kain0_0 Thank you for your long answer and valuable information. What do you mean by "releasable"? Is it the application with a bunch of installation/upgrade scripts, or not? If yes, I'm asking myself why it needed so long answer. So probably you mean a narrower meaning of the word?

Comment: @xarx Yes, By releasable I mean the totality of artefacts that you need to give to your customer (the CI/CD pipeline, the other organisation, some user on the internet) for them to receive a working edition of the program. As for why the long answer... well If I spent more time editing my thoughts, it'd be a lot shorter. ;) But alas this is as short as I could get it for now.

Comment: @Kain0_0 I meant: If your releasables include cmd and sql migration scripts (which you confirmed), then this is the "classical" structure of releases and everyone does or did that this way, don't they? When an operator performs an upgrade, he executes the bunch of scripts you've provided and checks the result before running the new version of your application. This has nothing to do with upgrade automation, does it? That said, there are certainly valuable points and ideas in your answer!

Comment: @xarx Yes you can do it that way, and you seem hell bent on proving your own position to be right. So yes strictly, technically speaking you are right, that constitutes a releasable. Does that solve the problem though? Think of the experience from the side receiving the release. How many hurdles do you want them to jump through? Which scripts need to be run in which order, under what circumstances. How many people with what technical knowledge are needed? Any reduction in this necessarily improves the customer experience, and reduces the support issues coming back due to user error.

Comment: @xarx and for clarity, no most people don't do it that way. In my own system we used to have a document with 36 deployment steps. Each was running an executable. over the last 5 years this has been reduced down to 5 steps. Backup the database. Get the package. Unzip the package. Run this program. If it works nothing else needed. If it fails restore the database. And even this exists as a single script on a deployment server that they run, and as yet we have not had it fail.

Comment: @Kain0_0 It took you 5 years to get to this point :-). I suppose that this required successive learning about your customer environment and processes, communication with your customer and gradual adjustments on both sides. Can this be performed in one step without all the knowledge about your customer you gradually obtained? I'd say no.

Comment: @xarx Regulatory rich environments always move slow. The appetite for risk is miniscule, and change is risk. What you have to do is prove that no change is the bigger risk.